# how to flatten dynamically nested json file

Tags: python, json

I need to convert a json file to csv file. The json file is nested as the following: as you see, for each user, there may be one role or multiple roles.

```
[{"userId": "82fac301", "login": "aa", 
"roles": [{"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:47.438", "dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.216", "roleId": "e818ddc2"}]}, 
{"userId": "88998d95", "login": "ab","roles": [
{"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:48.673", "dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.217", "roleId": "007e9495"}]}, {"userId": "dd4804cb", "login": "ac", "roles": [{"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:47.438", "dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.216", "roleId": "e818ddc2"},{"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:47.438", 
"dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.216", 
"roleId": "e818ddc2"}, {"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:49.056", "dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.217", "roleId": "5913416f"}]}]
```

then in csv file, I'd like the columns header look like this (the columns of roles can be dynamic since it's possible the user has up to 10 roles):

```
userId  login roles_1_datecreated  roles_1_dateModified  roles_1_roleId roles_2_datecreated  roles_2_dateModified roles_2_roleId  roles_3_...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely not prettiest solution, but it will work and accepts an unlimited number of roles.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"userId": "82fac301", "login": "aa", "roles": [{"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:47.438", "dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.216", "roleId": "e818ddc2"}]}, {"userId": "88998d95", "login": "ab","roles": [ {"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:48.673", "dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.217", "roleId": "007e9495"}]}, {"userId": "dd4804cb", "login": "ac", "roles": [{"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:47.438", "dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.216", "roleId": "e818ddc2"},{"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:47.438", "dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.216", "roleId": "e818ddc2"}, {"dateCreated": "2019-03-25T21:18:49.056", "dateModified": "2022-04-02T02:40:48.217", "roleId": "5913416f"}]}]

def csv_converter(contents):
    headers = ["userId", "login"]
    role_string = "roles_{0}_{1}"
    rows = []
    for userdict in contents:
        row = [userdict["userId"], userdict["login"]]
        for i, role in enumerate(userdict["roles"]):
            for k,v in role.items():
                header = role_string.format(i+1, k)
                if header not in headers:
                    headers.append(header)
                row.append(v)
        rows.append(row)
    rows = [row + ([""]*(len(headers) - len(row))) for row in rows]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=headers)
    df.to_csv('csvfile.csv')
#    write_to_file(headers, rows)

#def write_to_file(headers, rows):
#    with open("csvfile.csv","wt") as fd:
#        fd.write(",".join(headers) + "\n")
#        for line in rows:
#            amount = len(headers) - len(line)
#            if amount > 0:
#                line = line + ([""]*amount)
#            fd.write(",".join(line) + "\n")

csv_converter(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it works as expected!  Since I'm new to Python, now I wonder if it's possible to manipulate the list of headers and rows directly and then put them all into a dataframe, which can call to_csv() to write into a file directly? Thanks again.

Comment: sure it's possible but it will give you the same results.... @jian

Comment: Thanks, Alexander.  Yes, I want the same results, I just wonder how to finish the data manipulation within csv_converter, then we don't need to write another function like write_to_file :).